# CSS Can't change input text background colour in chrome & bootstrap

Tags: css

I am trying to change the background-color of my input text and its not changing in chrome, it works in Safari but not chrome:

```css
input {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<form action="login.php?action=login" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="submot" id="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Login" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: what version of chrome your using? it's working perfectly in my chrome version 83.0

Comment: With bootstrap?

Comment: yes with bootstrap,  https://jsfiddle.net/designerPrasanna/51z6vjw3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active  {
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset !important;
}
```

and this to change color in autofill textbox:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: yellow !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for this. Try this. This works and supports perfectly in all browsers.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $(".test");});
```

Try the following example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Method 01
  $(".test");
  
  //Method 02  
  //$(".test").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

```css
.test{
    background-color:#64b5f6;  /* Your color */
    color:#000;
    border:none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control test" />
```

*Happy coding!*